# Speeding up a for loop (or moving away from it), with some decision rules

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have a for loop, which attempts to check that, for every element in a vector `vals` it is contained exactly two times in 4 different vectors (`dp`, `up`, `de`, `ue`), but:

1. should only be found exactly once in `dp` or `de` and;
2. should only be found exactly once in `up` or `ue`

The vectors that I am trying to check are in the millions of elements, and it's taking hours, I'm thinking the below code could be sped up.

MRE:

```
vals <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f') # 6 elements to be verified

# only 1 of these two
dp <- c('a', 'c', 'd','f', 'f')
de <- c('b','a', 'd')
# only one of these two
up <- c('b', 'd', 'e')
ue <- c('c')    

i <- list()
for (val in vals) {
  dipa <- sum(grepl(val, dp)) # attemps to find val in dp and sums
  ulpa <- sum(grepl(val, up)) # attemps to find val in up and sums
  diex <- sum(grepl(val, de)) # attemps to find val in de and sums
  ulex <- sum(grepl(val, ue)) # attemps to find val in ue and sums
  f <- sum(sum(dipa) + sum(ulpa) + sum(diex) + sum(ulex)) == 2 # sum two # overall, it has to be found 2 times exactly
  pars <- dipa + diex == 1 # once in dipa or diex
  excs <- ulpa + ulex == 1 # once in ulpa or ulex
  if(isTRUE(f) & isTRUE(pars) & isTRUE(excs)) {
    i[val] <- 1 #if all of these 3 conditions are true, then add
  } else {
    next
  }
}
```

In the example above, `i` should hold only:

1. `b` (because it is found once in `up` and once in `de`
2. `c` (because it is found once in `dp` and once in `ue`

Every element of vals can appear as many times in any of the 4 other vectors, but ideally would only appear twice with the restrictions above.

Comment: There is some confusion in the `list`.  You already did the `sum` on `grepl` (wouldn't a `==` get the same result based on the example) and then again doing the `sum` on `f`

Comment: Which a? I agree that changing the sum to `f <- dipa + ulpa + diex + ulex == 2` might be faster, but marginally, ideally id be looking for some obscene performance increase, parallel processing or other options

Comment: I meant instead of `grepl`, you could use `==` if it is not a partial match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this work?

```
pervec <- sapply(list(dp,de,up,ue),
                 function(a) rowSums(sapply(a, `==`, vals)))
pervec
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    1    1    0
# [3,]    1    0    0    1
# [4,]    1    1    1    0
# [5,]    0    0    1    0
# [6,]    2    0    0    0

ind <- xor(pervec[,1] == 1, pervec[,2] == 1) & xor(pervec[,3] == 1, pervec[,4] == 1)
ind
# [1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

vals[ind]
# [1] "b" "c"
```

Comment: If you add one "b" in `de`, i.e. `de <- c('b', 'a',  'd',  'b')`, the output `vals[ind]` is still `[1] "b" "c"`, but theoretically `"b"` doesn't conform to the restriction.

Comment: I had interpreted it differently, that `dp` and the others were effectively *sets*. I interpret *"should only be found exactly once"* as *"found in one and not the other"*. If your interpretation is correct, then my answer is indeed not sufficient. (This is why a good example is important!)

Comment: @darren is correct, what is lacking in the example?

Comment: @erasmortg: some clarity, which you edited into your question. It's not necessarily that what you said is wrong, but that it is realistic to make different assumptions about what `dp` are meant to be. Too bad, this was *way* faster than a `for` loop :-)

Comment: See my edit, it handles repeats better with your updated inputs.

Comment: This did it `xor(parvec[,1] == 1, parvec[,2] == 1) & xor(parvec[,3] == 1, parvec[,4] == 1)`, I'll accept the answer, thank you!

Comment: Curious, how long did it take this to do what your previous implementation took hours?

Comment: I had to run multiple tests in different systems (because this one actually worked), the one machine that was used before, took ~3 days so there was no chance of checking against other systems. This one took around 1 hr I'd say?